# No me funciona el lazy load con lazysizes

Tags: html, css, imagen

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo con imágenes para que cargan de manera "perezosa" (con lazy load) pero no me funciona. Llevo ya mucho con esto y no logro encontrar el problema.

En el head tengo:

```
<style>

.contenedorfoto{
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<script src="js/lazysizes.js" async=""></script>
```

Después las imágenes las tengo de la forma:

```
<div class="contenedorfoto">
            <img alt="Desert Road" data-src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5531/9638435181_7e3e44c2b8_b.jpg" class="lazyload no-src" />
            <div class="contenedortexto">Imagen 2...</div>
</div>

<div class="contenedorfoto">
            <img alt="Desert Road" data-src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5531/9638435181_7e3e44c2b8_b.jpg" class="lazyload no-src" />
            <div class="contenedortexto">Imagen 3...</div>
</div>
```

Son muchas imágenes exactamente igual unas debajo de otras. Según la documentación del "plugin" lazysizes con eso deberia de funcionar. Pero no, no me funciona.

Si que aparece el archivo lazysizes.min.js en el inspector de elementos de Google Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has comprobado que la ruta `js/lazysizes.js` sea la correcta? Puedes ver en el inspector de elementos que se está cargando?

Comment: Sii si que es la correcta. Es lo primero que miré. Cuando estoy en la página del navegador pongo "Inspeccionar" pero no me aparece nada en la consola (no controlo tampoco el inspector de elementos).

Comment: Sin poder probarlo y leyendo la documentación veo que debería funcionar. Sólo se me ocurre el problema de la ruta. el fichero se llama `lazysizes.js` verdad? En la documentación aparece como `lazysizes.min.js`. Puede ser alguna incompatibilidad con otro plugin que tengas.

Comment: Sii pero también tengo el min.js y probandolo con este ultimo hace lo mismo. Cambio la ruta de los .js y sigue sin funcionar. No tengo ningún plugin mas. Solo ese.

Comment: Nooo. Tengo los dos en el mismo sitio y he probado con los dos, primero uno y luego otro, pero nada. En la imagen aparece el .min.js porque estaba probando con ese y llamaba a ese. Pero he probado con los dos.

Comment: La ruta es la correcta según tengo entendido. Tengo una carpeta con el proyecto. Dentro de la carpeta tengo el archivo "principal.html. Dentro de esta carpeta tengo otra carpeta llamada "js". Dentro de esa carpeta llamada "js" tengo los archivos "lazysizes.js" y "lazysizes.min.js". Por tanto para llamar al/los archivos lo hago de la forma "<script src="js/lazysizes.js">. ¿No es así?

Comment: Como habia dicho, estaba haciendo pruebas con los dos archivos y las dos localizaciones.

Answer (score 0):

He copiado el contenido de `lazysizes.min.js` y el código que has puesto arriba.

Funciona. No he cambiado nada. Por lo que diría que no está encontrando el fichero correctamente. Mira en el inspector de elementos si lo está encontrando.

Si utilizas Chrome, abre el inspector con la tecla `F12` y en la Pestaña `Sources` tiene que aparecer el archivo `lazysizes.min.js` en cuestión. Si no está, no lo está encontrando.

En caso de Mozilla Firefox, la pestaña se llama `Depurador`.

```js
/*! lazysizes - v4.0.0-rc3 */
!function(a,b){var c=b(a,a.document);a.lazySizes=c,"object"==typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=c)}(window,function(a,b){"use strict";if(b.getElementsByClassName){var c,d,e=b.documentElement,f=a.Date,g=a.HTMLPictureElement,h="addEventListener",i="getAttribute",j=a[h],k=a.setTimeout,l=a.requestAnimationFrame||k,m=a.requestIdleCallback,n=/^picture$/i,o=["load","error","lazyincluded","_lazyloaded"],p={},q=Array.prototype.forEach,r=function(a,b){return p[b]||(p[b]=new RegExp("(\\s|^)"+b+"(\\s|$)")),p[b].test(a[i]("class")||"")&&p[b]},s=function(a,b){r(a,b)||a.setAttribute("class",(a[i]("class")||"").trim()+" "+b)},t=function(a,b){var c;(c=r(a,b))&&a.setAttribute("class",(a[i]("class")||"").replace(c," "))},u=function(a,b,c){var d=c?h:"removeEventListener";c&&u(a,b),o.forEach(function(c){a[d](c,b)})},v=function(a,d,e,f,g){var h=b.createEvent("CustomEvent");return e||(e={}),e.instance=c,h.initCustomEvent(d,!f,!g,e),a.dispatchEvent(h),h},w=function(b,c){var e;!g&&(e=a.picturefill||d.pf)?e({reevaluate:!0,elements:[b]}):c&&c.src&&(b.src=c.src)},x=function(a,b){return(getComputedStyle(a,null)||{})[b]},y=function(a,b,c){for(c=c||a.offsetWidth;c<d.minSize&&b&&!a._lazysizesWidth;)c=b.offsetWidth,b=b.parentNode;return c},z=function(){var a,c,d=[],e=[],f=d,g=function(){var b=f;for(f=d.length?e:d,a=!0,c=!1;b.length;)b.shift()();a=!1},h=function(d,e){a&&!e?d.apply(this,arguments):(f.push(d),c||(c=!0,(b.hidden?k:l)(g)))};return h._lsFlush=g,h}(),A=function(a,b){return b?function(){z(a)}:function(){var b=this,c=arguments;z(function(){a.apply(b,c)})}},B=function(a){var b,c=0,d=125,e=666,g=e,h=function(){b=!1,c=f.now(),a()},i=m?function(){m(h,{timeout:g}),g!==e&&(g=e)}:A(function(){k(h)},!0);return function(a){var e;(a=a===!0)&&(g=44),b||(b=!0,e=d-(f.now()-c),0>e&&(e=0),a||9>e&&m?i():k(i,e))}},C=function(a){var b,c,d=99,e=function(){b=null,a()},g=function(){var a=f.now()-c;d>a?k(g,d-a):(m||e)(e)};return function(){c=f.now(),b||(b=k(g,d))}},D=function(){var g,l,m,o,p,y,D,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M=/^img$/i,N=/^iframe$/i,O="onscroll"in a&&!/glebot/.test(navigator.userAgent),P=0,Q=0,R=0,S=-1,T=function(a){R--,a&&a.target&&u(a.target,T),(!a||0>R||!a.target)&&(R=0)},U=function(a,c){var d,f=a,g="hidden"==x(b.body,"visibility")||"hidden"!=x(a,"visibility");for(F-=c,I+=c,G-=c,H+=c;g&&(f=f.offsetParent)&&f!=b.body&&f!=e;)g=(x(f,"opacity")||1)>0,g&&"visible"!=x(f,"overflow")&&(d=f.getBoundingClientRect(),g=H>d.left&&G<d.right&&I>d.top-1&&F<d.bottom+1);return g},V=function(){var a,f,h,j,k,m,n,p,q,r=c.elements;if((o=d.loadMode)&&8>R&&(a=r.length)){f=0,S++,null==K&&("expand"in d||(d.expand=e.clientHeight>500&&e.clientWidth>500?500:370),J=d.expand,K=J*d.expFactor),K>Q&&1>R&&S>2&&o>2&&!b.hidden?(Q=K,S=0):Q=o>1&&S>1&&6>R?J:P;for(;a>f;f++)if(r[f]&&!r[f]._lazyRace)if(O)if((p=r[f][i]("data-expand"))&&(m=1*p)||(m=Q),q!==m&&(y=innerWidth+m*L,D=innerHeight+m,n=-1*m,q=m),h=r[f].getBoundingClientRect(),(I=h.bottom)>=n&&(F=h.top)<=D&&(H=h.right)>=n*L&&(G=h.left)<=y&&(I||H||G||F)&&(d.loadHidden||"hidden"!=x(r[f],"visibility"))&&(l&&3>R&&!p&&(3>o||4>S)||U(r[f],m))){if(ba(r[f]),k=!0,R>9)break}else!k&&l&&!j&&4>R&&4>S&&o>2&&(g[0]||d.preloadAfterLoad)&&(g[0]||!p&&(I||H||G||F||"auto"!=r[f][i](d.sizesAttr)))&&(j=g[0]||r[f]);else ba(r[f]);j&&!k&&ba(j)}},W=B(V),X=function(a){s(a.target,d.loadedClass),t(a.target,d.loadingClass),u(a.target,Z),v(a.target,"lazyloaded")},Y=A(X),Z=function(a){Y({target:a.target})},$=function(a,b){try{a.contentWindow.location.replace(b)}catch(c){a.src=b}},_=function(a){var b,c=a[i](d.srcsetAttr);(b=d.customMedia[a[i]("data-media")||a[i]("media")])&&a.setAttribute("media",b),c&&a.setAttribute("srcset",c)},aa=A(function(a,b,c,e,f){var g,h,j,l,o,p;(o=v(a,"lazybeforeunveil",b)).defaultPrevented||(e&&(c?s(a,d.autosizesClass):a.setAttribute("sizes",e)),h=a[i](d.srcsetAttr),g=a[i](d.srcAttr),f&&(j=a.parentNode,l=j&&n.test(j.nodeName||"")),p=b.firesLoad||"src"in a&&(h||g||l),o={target:a},p&&(u(a,T,!0),clearTimeout(m),m=k(T,2500),s(a,d.loadingClass),u(a,Z,!0)),l&&q.call(j.getElementsByTagName("source"),_),h?a.setAttribute("srcset",h):g&&!l&&(N.test(a.nodeName)?$(a,g):a.src=g),f&&(h||l)&&w(a,{src:g})),a._lazyRace&&delete a._lazyRace,t(a,d.lazyClass),z(function(){(!p||a.complete&&a.naturalWidth>1)&&(p?T(o):R--,X(o))},!0)}),ba=function(a){var b,c=M.test(a.nodeName),e=c&&(a[i](d.sizesAttr)||a[i]("sizes")),f="auto"==e;(!f&&l||!c||!a[i]("src")&&!a.srcset||a.complete||r(a,d.errorClass))&&(b=v(a,"lazyunveilread").detail,f&&E.updateElem(a,!0,a.offsetWidth),a._lazyRace=!0,R++,aa(a,b,f,e,c))},ca=function(){if(!l){if(f.now()-p<999)return void k(ca,999);var a=C(function(){d.loadMode=3,W()});l=!0,d.loadMode=3,W(),j("scroll",function(){3==d.loadMode&&(d.loadMode=2),a()},!0)}};return{_:function(){p=f.now(),c.elements=b.getElementsByClassName(d.lazyClass),g=b.getElementsByClassName(d.lazyClass+" "+d.preloadClass),L=d.hFac,j("scroll",W,!0),j("resize",W,!0),a.MutationObserver?new MutationObserver(W).observe(e,{childList:!0,subtree:!0,attributes:!0}):(e[h]("DOMNodeInserted",W,!0),e[h]("DOMAttrModified",W,!0),setInterval(W,999)),j("hashchange",W,!0),["focus","mouseover","click","load","transitionend","animationend","webkitAnimationEnd"].forEach(function(a){b[h](a,W,!0)}),/d$|^c/.test(b.readyState)?ca():(j("load",ca),b[h]("DOMContentLoaded",W),k(ca,2e4)),c.elements.length?(V(),z._lsFlush()):W()},checkElems:W,unveil:ba}}(),E=function(){var a,c=A(function(a,b,c,d){var e,f,g;if(a._lazysizesWidth=d,d+="px",a.setAttribute("sizes",d),n.test(b.nodeName||""))for(e=b.getElementsByTagName("source"),f=0,g=e.length;g>f;f++)e[f].setAttribute("sizes",d);c.detail.dataAttr||w(a,c.detail)}),e=function(a,b,d){var e,f=a.parentNode;f&&(d=y(a,f,d),e=v(a,"lazybeforesizes",{width:d,dataAttr:!!b}),e.defaultPrevented||(d=e.detail.width,d&&d!==a._lazysizesWidth&&c(a,f,e,d)))},f=function(){var b,c=a.length;if(c)for(b=0;c>b;b++)e(a[b])},g=C(f);return{_:function(){a=b.getElementsByClassName(d.autosizesClass),j("resize",g)},checkElems:g,updateElem:e}}(),F=function(){F.i||(F.i=!0,E._(),D._())};return function(){var b,c={lazyClass:"lazyload",loadedClass:"lazyloaded",loadingClass:"lazyloading",preloadClass:"lazypreload",errorClass:"lazyerror",autosizesClass:"lazyautosizes",srcAttr:"data-src",srcsetAttr:"data-srcset",sizesAttr:"data-sizes",minSize:40,customMedia:{},init:!0,expFactor:1.5,hFac:.8,loadMode:2,loadHidden:!0};d=a.lazySizesConfig||a.lazysizesConfig||{};for(b in c)b in d||(d[b]=c[b]);a.lazySizesConfig=d,k(function(){d.init&&F()})}(),c={cfg:d,autoSizer:E,loader:D,init:F,uP:w,aC:s,rC:t,hC:r,fire:v,gW:y,rAF:z}}});
```

```css
.contenedorfoto{
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedorfoto">
            <img alt="Desert Road" data-src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5531/9638435181_7e3e44c2b8_b.jpg" class="lazyload no-src" />
            <div class="contenedortexto">Imagen 2...</div>
</div>

<div class="contenedorfoto">
            <img alt="Desert Road" data-src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5531/9638435181_7e3e44c2b8_b.jpg" class="lazyload no-src" />
            <div class="contenedortexto">Imagen 3...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exacto. En el inspector de elementos si que aparece el archivo lazysizes.min.js. Ajunto captura de pantalla en la pregunta.

Comment: Estás trabajando sobre local? O en servidor directamente?

Comment: En local en local. Nada de servidor (y que lo rebiente todo jjj)